# Nhibenate - DOS Attack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, post

One of the testers in my company found an error on my ASP.Net MVC 3 solution, that I believe is pretty common.

One post to the server it can handle. But if you send a lot of posts, like a **denial-of-service attack (DoS attack)** it thrown an exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Initializing[UseSoft.ProdMaster.Domain.Entities.CustomerOrderHeader#567]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: UseSoft.ProdMaster.Domain.Entities.CustomerOrderHeader.CustomerOrderLines, no session or session was closed
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Initializing[UseSoft.ProdMaster.Domain.Entities.CustomerOrderHeader#567]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: UseSoft.ProdMaster.Domain.Entities.CustomerOrderHeader.CustomerOrderLines, no session or session was closed

Source Error:

Line 880:
Line 881:
Line 882:            return
Line 883:                Json(
Line 884:                    new


Source File: C:\Projects\DavidPM\Hosts\ProdMaster.Hosts.Web\Areas\Sales\Controllers\CustomerOrderController.cs    Line: 882

Stack Trace:

[LazyInitializationException: Initializing[UseSoft.ProdMaster.Domain.Entities.CustomerOrderHeader#567]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: UseSoft.ProdMaster.Domain.Entities.CustomerOrderHeader.CustomerOrderLines, no session or session was closed]
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ThrowLazyInitializationException(String message) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:484
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ThrowLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:474
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Initialize(Boolean writing) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:465
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Read() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:264
   NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Collection\Generic\PersistentGenericBag.cs:142
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +63
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +217
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   UseSoft.ProdMaster.Hosts.Web.Areas.Sales.Controllers.CustomerOrderController.SaveOrUpdateOrderLines(CustomerOrderModel customerOrderModel) in C:\Projects\DavidPM\Hosts\ProdMaster.Hosts.Web\Areas\Sales\Controllers\CustomerOrderController.cs:882
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +162
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8862381
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

The is described bellow:

Click in a button many times. Or click once and press enter, it will send a lot of requests to the server "Post".

The Model Basically is:

```
public class CustomerOrderModel
{
    public CustomerOrderModel()
    {
        this.CustomerOrderLines = new List<CustomerOrderLineModel>();
        this.CustomerOrderHeader = new CustomerOrderHeaderModel();
    }

    public CustomerOrderHeaderModel CustomerOrderHeader
    { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerOrderLineModel> CustomerOrderLines
    { get; set; }

}
```

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveOrUpdateOrderLines(  CustomerOrderModel customerOrderModel)
        {

  if (customerOrderModel.CustomerOrderHeader.OrderNumber == 0)
             {
                 customerOrderModel.CustomerOrderHeader.OrderNumber = this.CustomerOrderService.CreateOrUpdate(customerOrderHeader, false);
             }
```

return
                Json(
                    new
                    {
                        OrderNumber = customerOrderModel.CustomerOrderHeader.OrderNumber,
                        CustomerOrderLines = new
                            {
                                CustomerOrderLine = (
                                    from ordeline in custOrderHeader.CustomerOrderLines
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Id = ordeline.Id,
                                        LineNumber = ordeline.LineNumber,
                                        LineStatus = ordeline.LineStatus
                                    }

```
                            ).ToArray()

                        }
                }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            );

}
```

The CustomerOrder Service:

```
 public class CustomerOrderService : ServiceBase, ICustomerOrderService
    {

 public long CreateOrUpdate(CustomerOrderHeader customerOrderHeader, bool updateCustomerOrderHeader)
        {
            using (var session = this.SessionManager.OpenSession())
            {
                var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

                try
                {
                    //TODO: CHECKS IF PARTNER EXISTS
                    bool existsPartner = false;
                    long number = 0;
                    if (this.PartnerService.FindByName(customerOrderHeader.Partner.Name) != null)
                    {
                        existsPartner = true;
                    }

                    //CREATE PARTNER AND PARTNER ADDRESSES
                    if (!existsPartner)
                    {
                        this.PartnerService.Create(customerOrderHeader.Partner as Partner);
                    }



                    if (!updateCustomerOrderHeader)
                    {
                        number = this.CustomerOrderHeaderService.Create(customerOrderHeader, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.CustomerOrderHeaderService.Create(customerOrderHeader, false);
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return number;


                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    session.Close();
                }
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomerOrderService"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sessionManager">
        /// The session manager.
        /// </param>
        public CustomerOrderService(ISessionManager sessionManager)
        {
            this.SessionManager = sessionManager;
        }
}
```

The CustomerOrderHeaderService:

```
public long Create(CustomerOrderHeader customerOrderHeader, bool firstTime)
        {


            using (var session = this.SessionManager.OpenSession())
            {
            //    var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

            //    try
            //    {




                    if (firstTime)
                    {
                        foreach (var customerOrderLine in customerOrderHeader.CustomerOrderLines)
                        {
                            customerOrderLine.CustomerOrderHeader = customerOrderHeader;
                        }

                        customerOrderHeader.OrderNumber = this.NextOrderNumber();
                        session.Save(customerOrderHeader);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CustomerOrderHeader customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged =
                            this.FindByOrderNumber(customerOrderHeader.OrderNumber);

                        customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged.CopyDomainProperties(
                            customerOrderHeader, new[]
                                                     {
                                                         "Id", 
                                                         "Partner", 
                                                         "DataOwner", 
                                                         "dataOwner", 
                                                         "SysCreatedOn",
                                                         "SysCreatedBy",
                                                         "CustomerOrderLines"
                                                     });
                        customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged = UpdateLines(customerOrderHeader, customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged);
                        List<ICustomerOrderLine> linestoBeInserted = GetTheLineNumbersToBeInserted(customerOrderHeader);

                        foreach (var customerOrderLine in linestoBeInserted)
                        {
                            customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged.CustomerOrderLines.Add(customerOrderLine);
                            customerOrderLine.CustomerOrderHeader = customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged;
                        }

                        session.Update(customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged);
                    }

            //        transaction.Commit();
            }
            //    catch (Exception ex)
            //    {
            //        transaction.Rollback();
            //        throw ex;
            //    }
            //    finally
            //    {
            //        session.Close();
            //    }
            //}
            //throw new System.ArgumentException();

            return customerOrderHeader.OrderNumber;
        }


public class CustomerOrderHeaderService : ServiceBase, ICustomerOrderHeaderService
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomerOrderHeaderService"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sessionManager">
        /// The session manager.
        /// </param>
        public CustomerOrderHeaderService(ISessionManager sessionManager)
        {
            this.SessionManager = sessionManager;
        }

        #endregion

 public long Create(CustomerOrderHeader customerOrderHeader, bool firstTime)
        {


            using (var session = this.SessionManager.OpenSession())
            {
            //    var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

            //    try
            //    {




                    if (firstTime)
                    {
                        foreach (var customerOrderLine in customerOrderHeader.CustomerOrderLines)
                        {
                            customerOrderLine.CustomerOrderHeader = customerOrderHeader;
                        }

                        customerOrderHeader.OrderNumber = this.NextOrderNumber();
                        session.Save(customerOrderHeader);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CustomerOrderHeader customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged =
                            this.FindByOrderNumber(customerOrderHeader.OrderNumber);

                        customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged.CopyDomainProperties(
                            customerOrderHeader, new[]
                                                     {
                                                         "Id", 
                                                         "Partner", 
                                                         "DataOwner", 
                                                         "dataOwner", 
                                                         "SysCreatedOn",
                                                         "SysCreatedBy",
                                                         "CustomerOrderLines"
                                                     });
                        customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged = UpdateLines(customerOrderHeader, customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged);
                        List<ICustomerOrderLine> linestoBeInserted = GetTheLineNumbersToBeInserted(customerOrderHeader);

                        foreach (var customerOrderLine in linestoBeInserted)
                        {
                            customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged.CustomerOrderLines.Add(customerOrderLine);
                            customerOrderLine.CustomerOrderHeader = customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged;
                        }

                        session.Update(customerOrderHeaderToBeChanged);
                    }

            //        transaction.Commit();
            }
            //    catch (Exception ex)
            //    {
            //        transaction.Rollback();
            //        throw ex;
            //    }
            //    finally
            //    {
            //        session.Close();
            //    }
            //}
            //throw new System.ArgumentException();

            return customerOrderHeader.OrderNumber;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase your connection pool limits can help make it last longer under this, as long as you don't saturate the server/network with too many.

Open and close database connections as late and early (respectively) as possible. You may want to switch your session open/close from per-request (or whatever you are using) to on-use.

In your case, since it's a button on the interface, you can temporarily disable it (with JavaScript) for a period of time so the user can't keep clicking it faster than they should ever need to.

Regardless, you should rate limit the incoming requests either at the network or IIS level.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you aren't sharing objects across multiple NHibernate sessions.

That error could occur if Session #1 loads an object that Session #2 tries to commit.